# Are there any frameworks available for Integration testing in Angular 5

Tags: angular

I am trying to write integration tests for angular app, where I don't want to mock the backend and would want to test the response that is received. Is there any way by which I can do this in Angular.

Comment: [Have a look](https://angular.io/guide/testing)

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to make ACTUAL http requests in your unit tests and then test the data coming back ? If that's the case you can just use the regular HTTP client

Comment: Try protractor, Angular CLI uses it by default with `ng e2e`.  Follow the link given by @SouravDutta above.